# How to change a predeterminate underline color in an Input with Materialize w/Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, materialize

I really try so hard to change the underline color but I can't, I don't know where do that, please help me!

[image: I want to change that green color for another one.]

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control white-text' %>
          <br>
          <%= f.label :password %>
          <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control white-text' %>
          <br>


          <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn" ,style:"color:white;background-color: #EEB756;" %>
          <% end %>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html) you can change the underline colour in CSS by modifying the colour of `border-bottom` and `box-shadow` of the element containing the input element (that is the one with the class `input-field`)

so maybe it would be something like this:

```
.input-field input[type=email] {
   border-bottom: 1px solid red;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the class `.input-field`, and add more specific selector, for example:

```
.input-field input
```

or to email type of input

```
.input-field input[type=email]
```

or to focused field:

```
.input-field input[type=text]:focus
```

And set the border style:

```
.input-field input[type=text]:focus{
     border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

You can read more in **Materialize** documentation: http://materializecss.com/forms.html

EDIT: edited as suggested by @Toby1Kenobi

Comment: You beat me to it! In this case shouldn't you use `[type=email]`?

Comment: The docs also seem to suggest modifying the `box-shadow` property

Comment: @Toby1Kenobi you're right,`[type=email]` selector can be used. Yes, a little bit faster:)